# Hibernate Envers: How to get revision from historical entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I must be missing something obvious; however I am struggling to find an answer to a problem I am having with Hibernate Envers.

Let's say that I have entity class called MyObject that is audited using envers.

If I get the current copy of an instance of MyObject doing something like:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
MyObject myobject1 = (MyObject) session.get(MyObject.class, 1234);
```

And I get an historical copy (from revision 2) of the same instance:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(session);
MyObject myobject2 = reader.find(MyObject.class, 1234, 2);
```

Is there any way of distinguishing myobject1 from myobject2? How would I know that myobject1 was the current copy and myobject2 was from revsion 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "official" way. Both are just objects instantiated with different data.

You could, although, check if the `session` contains `myobject1`/`myobject2` (using the `contians` method: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html). This will work as long as you don't clear or change the persistence context, and will return `true` for "current" entities and `false` for the historical ones. But that's more of a work-around than a proper solution.

Comment: Adam, thanks for the suggestion; however `contains` does not help me determine the revision of a historical entity. It must be known internally, as it is possible to walk relationships and get the the correct entity revision. I guess I will have to dig deeper to see if I can expose the revision.

Comment: Well, it will be the same revision you used to read the original historical entity :)

And yes, the revision is stored in the proxies that are used to walk the relationships.

Comment: I have tried to simplify this question as much a possible to strip out the noise. I hope that is not making my point less clear! At the point that I want to know if the entity I have is current or a historical revision, I do not know the revision that was used to get the entity. I was hoping for something like: `Long revision = session.contains(myobject) ? null : reader.getRevision(myobject);`

Comment: There's no such method currently, unfortunately.